# Is using "safe bet" in this sentence correct?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Is this example correct:

It is always a safe bet to call someone whenever you need.

In my mind this example means that this someone will not turn you down. 
Is it correct?

Comment: Welcome to ELL. This sentence is not grammatically correct: It doesn't say what you need. It must end with **...need to** or **...need help** or **...need *something***.  Also there is no way of knowing (from this sentence) why it's a safe bet: you cannot presume that it is because someone won't turn you down. It could simply be that the alternatives are much worse.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence is incomplete -- "whenever you need" requires an object, even if it's the simple infinitive implied by the particle "to": "whenever you need to [call someone].

It's hard to say whether "safe bet" is correct, since the sentence is incomplete.  However, it probably is incorrect, since it implies success, and there's no way to know if anyone you call will be responsive to your call.  However, it's a safe bet to use the phrase when referring to a sure thing: "it's a safe bet that your call will go through if you've paid your phone bill."